# How to view ICMP Redirect Logs

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-kernel, icmp

I have read on multiple sources that there is are logs for rejected ICMP redirect messages, one of them being "Understanding Linux Network Internals: Guided Tour to Networking on Linux" By Christian Benvenuti. However I am unable to find these logs (I am running Ubuntu 18).

I am trying to understand why if my device receives and ICMP redirect to an IPv4 address which is not part of any subnet it is rejected. Technically this should be accepted as secure_redirects = 0, shared_media = 1 and accept_redirects = 1.